# How can I pass a string into a the .close() method of the FileResponse object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, class, web

I am altering the behavior of the .close() method of the FileResponse object.  FileResponse is a subclass of StreamingHttpResponse which is very similar to the HttpResponse object.

What I am trying to do is take a string of text, save it into a .docx, send that docx to the browser, then delete that docx.  Everything is working great until I try to delete the .docx.  It doesn't look like I can delete the file before the response is sent because the response needs the file, but I can't do anything at all after the response has been sent because the view has completed its task and sent a response.  A potential solution I have found is to modify the .close() method of the FileResponse object (similar to the HttpResponse object) to delete the file.

Great.  However, I do not know how to pass the path to the file to the .close() method.  This might be an elementary question, but I generally avoid editing built in class methods.

Code below.

```
import logging
from django.http import FileResponse
import os  

logger = logging.getLogger("django")

#editing the default closing behavior of the file response object to delete the file 
that it just sent.
class SendAndDeleteExport(FileResponse):
    def close(self):
        super(SendAndDeleteExport, self).close()
        # do whatever you want, this is the last codepoint in request handling
        logger.info(self)
        # os.remove(desired_path + "/export.docx"

        if self.status_code == 200:
            logger.info('HttpResponse successful: %s' % self.status_code)
```

I am getting "HttpResponse successful: 200" in the console, so I know I'm making some progress, but I need to pass the file path from the view to this .close()

views.py

```
from .helpers import SendAndDeleteExport
from docx import Document
import os

def export(request):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    desired_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'exports')
    logger.info(desired_path)
    document = Document()
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  edited againa')
    document.save(desired_path + "/export.docx")
    file_to_user = SendAndDeleteExport(open(desired_path + "/export.docx", 'rb'))
    return file_to_user
```

The .docx file is indeed being generated and sent to the client as a download which is the desired behavior, but I don't want to hold onto all these exported files indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request_finished` signal combine with threading-isolation object `local` to achieve that deleting the file after responding success. django signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#request-finished

> django.core.signals.request_finished
> Sent when Django finishes delivering an HTTP response to the client.

for more detail, please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/

```py
from threading import local

from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse

local = local()  # for threading isolation 

def export(request):
    # do something
    local.path = 'your_file_path'
    return HttpResponse('ok')

def when_request_finished(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    this function will be executed when any request finished(got response)
    """
    if hasattr(local, 'path'):
        # do something
        print(local.path)

request_finished.connect(when_request_finished, dispatch_uid="when_request_finished_identifier")
```